# iPhone App Missing Graphics

Tags: iphone, graphics, opengl-es

I'm just encountering a new problem with my first iPhone App.
On my local device with Xcode everything runs well.
But now I uploaded my App to iTunes Connect and now it's live and one can download it.

But when I use a promotional Code and download my own app, some graphics are missing and there's just a white graphic with no image...
But I think if apple had seen this they wouldn't allow the app to be downloaded?!

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your graphics files were actually copied into your project, and not just referenced, since then they would only exist in their original place on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing both the App Store version and the development built version on the same device? Completely delete the app and redownload it from the App Store. It acts funky when you try to replace the development version with the App Store version.

Comment: Yeah I just always do this :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when you add the graphics to your app,you forgot to mark the add the files to main folder!I had the same problem!
Sorry for my english!